# Simplify3D with error in preview?

Tags: g-code, simplify3d

I am trying to print a belt but when I preview it, the model doesn't fully render

[image: Screenshot of half rendered preview]

It isn't rendering the full model correctly. The model is rendering halfway but isn't fully which is why you can still see the infill when the slider is at max which isn't normal.

This is what it *should* look like:

[image: Screenshot of fully rendered preview]

I have a 0.4 nozzle and those with a 0.6 have been able to print this. What is going on?

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE! What have you tried to change in order to get it to render? Is it throwing any exceptions? What *isn't* it doing exactly?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 it isn't rendering the full model correctly. The model is rendering halfway but isn't fully which is why you can still see the infill when the slider is at max which isn't norma

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I added what the model looks like and what it looks like when rendered

Comment: The second image helps a lot so we can understand *what it should look like*. Is this a print you got from Thingiverse?

Comment: Look in the lower right corner - can you setting it to 300 layers or 400?

Answer (score 1):

First I thought that the model was improperly modeled due inverted faces or any missing line to close that faces but, I rendered the same STL to be printed 0.4 nozzle with height 0.2mm and looks pretty well.

[image]

Then I suspected that you were trying to print with 0.4 nozzle at 0.6 layers, which this is totally wrong but, I decided to set the 3D simplify and do the test. The program just show a warning about first layer height adhesion, the click OK and the part is rendered correctly.

[image]

However the recommended settings for a 0.4 nozzle should be less than 80% diameter = 0.32mm as maximum to get a proper bonding.

So, I think that you need to download the part and render it again. The time to process this render under XP with an small PC last for 5 minutes. So on bigger PC's will be faster.

Here is the link where I downloaded the "[belt Komplett 805](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3270948)"